# Stack of integer array push operation

Tags: java

I have declared a stack of integer array -

```
Stack<int[]> stack = new Stack<int[]>();
```

When I am pushing an object to stack using following code, I am getting an error -

```
stack.push({0,0});
```

But it works when I use the following code -

```
stack.push(new int[]{0,0});
```

So I am bit confused why the first way did not work. Does `{0,0}` not declare a new array object which can be pushed on the stack?

Comment: Short answer: no, it doesn't declare a new array object.

Comment: Your intuition was correct. In Java, you need to be specific about everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using the braces `{0,0}` doesn't by itself create and initialize a new array.  You may be confused by the following syntax that makes this look like it's possible.

```
int[] someArray = {0, 0};
```

This syntax allows just the braces, and not the `new int[]` before it, only when it's part of a declaration.  You don't have a declaration, so it's invalid syntax.  Without a declaration, the `new int[]` part is required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
stack.push(new int[] {0,0});
```

or,

```
int[] array = {0, 0} // creates a new array
stack.push(array);
```

Because, only `{0, 0}` does not create any *new* array, that's why you get errors.
[Read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java)